# QWebview/webkit disable zoom double click

Tags: zooming, qt5, qwebview

I would like to help with QWebView. I'm trying to create a software that will open a web page, so far everything was right, but I came across an issue with QWebView. On double click with the mouse is zooming.

```
WebView {
    id: webviewHelp
    anchors.fill: parent
    smooth: false
    url: "http://stackoverflow.com"
    objectName: "webView"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of the use of mobile devices that need disabled some features that bring comfort to small devices. Put on `head` this code

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; 
          maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=no;target-densitydpi=72;" />

    ...
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that your full code?
If not then check for a onDoubleClick property, I'm not familiar with Qt5 much but on Qt4 it had to be a child of a Flickable then the onDoubleClick property a child of the WebView calling heuristicZoom.

Comment: Yes, this is full code,i tried to use onDoubleClick with  Flicktable, but accused a error that doesn't exist this property. i am using the import QtQuick 2.2 e QtWebKit 3.0.

Comment: I meant try onDoubleClick with the WebView, if it exists it may override it.
something like onDoubleClick{console.log("Double clicked!")}